# How to properly handle inflated views inside a RecyclerView ViewHolder?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have multiple layout that will be inflated in my `RecyclerView` ViewHolder, the views are inflated depending on the dataset that is being pass to the ViewHolder, I know how to use `getItemViewType()` but in my case it is not applicable, so for example the dataset contain 1,2,3 it will inflate all the view to the ViewHolder container(LinearLayout).

**My ViewHolder with a LinearLayout Container :**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <include layout="@layout/layout_header" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lnr_container"     
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    </LinearLayout>
                <include layout="@layout/layout_footer" />
            </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**ViewHolder1 :**

Here I created a reference of the view with the variable and if the view is recycled I will just check if the variable is not null so for example the recyclerView I will just reset the data.

```
    private class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @BindView(R.id.lnr_container)
    LinearLayout mLnrContainer;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;

    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data){
        mLnrContainer.removeAllViews();

        if (data.has("1")){
            if (mRecyclerView == null){
                mRecyclerView  = new RecyclerView(itemView.getContext());
                // other implementation
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(itemView.getContext(),data));
            }else {
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().setData(data);
            }

            addView(mRecyclerView);
        }
        if (data.has("2")){
            mImageView  = new ImageView(itemView.getContext());
            addView(mImageView);
        }
        if (data.has("3")){
            mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,mLnrContainer,false);
            addView(mLayout);
        }
    }

    private void addView(View view){
        mLnrContainer.addView(view);
    }
}
```

**ViewHolder2 :**

```
private class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @BindView(R.id.lnr_container)
    LinearLayout mLnrContainer;

    public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data){
        mLnrContainer.removeAllViews();

        if (data.has("1")){
            RecyclerView mRecyclerView  = new RecyclerView(itemView.getContext(),data);
            addView(mRecyclerView);
        }
        if (data.has("2")){
            ImageView mImageView  = new ImageView(itemView.getContext());
            addView(mImageView);
        }
        if (data.has("3")){
            LinearLayout  mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,mLnrContainer,false);
            addView(mLayout);
        }
    }

    private void addView(View view){
        mLnrContainer.addView(view);
    }
}
```

I am wondering and confused which of this ViewHolders should be implemented in my code, Is there a difference that might affect if the ViewHolder is recycled? Thank you for your answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

ViewHolder was made specifically to prevent excessive inflation, doing so in onBind will result in very poor performance.

I would use multiple `itemViewType`s and inflate the layouts accordingly, just to have at least something to recycle. If those "1, 2, 3" are not mutually exclusive, that gives 8 different layout combinations.

Modify your RecyclerView.Adapter to reflect possible combinations:

```
private static final int VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_RECYCLER = 1;
private static final int VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_IMAGEVIEW = 1 << 1;
private static final int VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_LINEAR = 1 << 2;
// shared view pool
private final RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool adapterSharedRecycledViewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    JSONObject data = dataList.get(position);
    int viewType = 0;
    // each type is a flag in viewType int, this returns values from 0 to 7
    if(data.has("1"))
        viewType = VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_RECYCLER;
    if(data.has("2"))
        viewType |= VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_IMAGEVIEW;
    if(data.has("3"))
        viewType |= VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_LINEAR;
    return viewType;
}
```

Then check the flags when creating viewholder (for example pass viewType as constructor argument):

```
private class ViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @BindView(R.id.lnr_container)
    LinearLayout mLnrContainer;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;

    public ViewHolder3(View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);

        // only need to inflate extra views once
        if((viewType & VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_RECYCLER) > 0){
            mRecyclerView  = new RecyclerView(itemView.getContext());
            // adapter must handle empty dataset
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(itemView.getContext(), null));
            // optimization to share views between other items
            mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(adapterSharedRecycledViewPool);
            addView(mRecyclerView);
        }
        if((viewType & VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_IMAGEVIEW) > 0){
            mImageView  = new ImageView(itemView.getContext());
            addView(mImageView);
        }
        if((viewType & VIEWTYPE_FLAG_HAS_LINEAR) > 0){
            mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,mLnrContainer,false);
            addView(mLayout);
        }
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data){
        // views must be ready now
        if (data.has("1")){
            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().setData(data);
        }
        if (data.has("2")){
            // bind image view if needed
        }
        if (data.has("3")){
            // bind data to linear layout as needed
        }
    }

    private void addView(View view){
        mLnrContainer.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Notice the `setRecycledViewPool`: this allows nested recyclerViews to share the views created by other nested recyclerViews. This will increase the performance but ViewHolders created by `someAdapter` must be a static class (not an inner class of an adapter) since this allows ViewHolders to traverse between different RecyclerViews / Adapters.